# Details to setup Merchant account

Tags: android, google-play, merchant-account

I need to open an account in android market and also need to setup merchant account so can any one please tell me the details need to setup Merchant account.

As i know the procedure to setup account for free applications.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer this question, I would recommend you only ask coding related questions here, otherwise you may find your answer id downvoted.

As for my answer: Have you looked at the help guides Google provide? There is an entire section dedicated to setting up a merchant account, which can be found here [Set up your Merchant account](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188486)
. It tells you what is required to setup your account.

Comment: I will follow to words...I tried hard to get info about this but i couldnt find anywhere so i thought of posting question here. Can i get step by step details on that please

Comment: It tells you in step by steps at that url...